# odoo-bin: error: option --addons-path: no such directory: '../mymodules'

Tags: python, centos, erp, odoo-10

When I tried to setup odoo 10.0 community edition at the last step on CentOS 6.9, 
executing command of

```
./odoo-bin --addons-path=addons,../mymodules --db-filter=mydb$
```

it went wrong with

```
odoo-bin: error: option --addons-path: no such directory: '../mymodules'
```

Did I lose some module to install? How con I solve the problem?

My odoo directory is on /root/odoo.

Comment: The error message is rather clear: that path does not exist. If you don't have it you should remove it from the command line.

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry but thank u, it did work. i was busy doing my business and forgot to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems *mymodules* folder is empty. Whenever we add any empty folder path to Odoo, it's give same error as you faced.

So you can remove that empty folder addons path.

If you have addons module in your *mymodules* folder then make sure it locate proper position.

For example:

In your case, *mymodules* must be parent level of *addons* folder. If *mymodules* is same level at *addons* folder then we can use following style to start Odoo server:

```
./odoo-bin --addons=addons,mymodules --db-filter=mydb$
```

Comment: yes, i remove the dir from the path and no error occured. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

the path of your directory is wrong give full path srarting from home/..../ mymodules

```
./odoo-bin --addons=addons,../mymodules --db-filter=mydb$
```

Comment: but there's no mymodules at all, finally i remove it from my command.